# Cannot open an old ASP.NET 1.1 application (solution) in VS 2003

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-1.1

I have a Problem with an very old **ASP.NET 1.1** application. I cannot open (load) it in **Visual Studio 2003** (on a Win 2003 server) any more. I get an error message,that the component for the communication with the "Front Page - Server Extensions" cannot be found (I use a german VS 2003, so I have not the exact English message). The extensions are installed. That can be the reason for that respectively how can I solve this problem.

Another Question: Is there a possibility to open an ASP.NET 1.1 application in **VS 2010**? Tthe upgrade wizard tries to convert it, but the conversion results in errors.

Comment: how does it behave if you open the solution file with visual studio 2010? does it show the upgrade wizard or what?

Comment: What os are you using? I know vs 2003 is not compatible with windows 7. It can be done, but it's tricky -http://www.bernzilla.com/2009/05/26/using-visual-studio-net-2003-on-windows-7/

Comment: @Elmex: have you tried removing the assemblies, then rebuild the application?

Comment: Win Server 2003 (but look at the description ;-) )

Comment: Have you checked to see if Visual Studio 2003 has the latest service pack files installed?

Comment: Do make sure to patch up your Visual Studio, it will solve a myriad of baffling problems you'll discover later.

Comment: Might consider running VS as Administrator ... (and turn off UAC for a bit) ... You might be looking at a security extension?

Comment: can you run it on the local dev server? can you create a new web project in the dev environment? can you load it on a different machine?

Comment: Are the FrontPage Server Extensions installed and enabled in your IIS?

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly you need to create a virtual directory in IIS that maps to the directory containing the ASP.NET project - you may need to tweak the solution file in the process so the ASP.NET project path matches your IIS virtual directory path(e.g. http://localhost/VIRTUALDIRECTORY/ASP.NETProject.csproj). 
Ensure any .suo and .webinfo files within the solution and project folders are deleted before opening the "tweaked" solution file.

Answer (score 1):

"Cannot find the components for communicating with FrontPage server exstensions". I believe this might be the error message.

Logon as another user and see if 'they' get the same problem. If the problem goes away as a different user. Destroying your local profile and then rebuilding it. Remember to back it up first as you will lose everything associated with this profile.

If that doesn't work then you should try the following (It concerns removing Beta 2 of VS 2002/2003, but the line that interested me was): http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=KB;EN-US;Q312383

Hope that helps.